# accessing std::vector values in shared_memory using [] parenthesis

Tags: c++, boost

i'am creating vector in shared memory using boost shared_memory_manager template:

```
using namespace boost::interprocess;

typedef allocator<nIcon*, managed_shared_memory::segment_manager>  ShmemAllocator;


typedef std::vector<nIcon*, ShmemAllocator> icons_v;
if(already_running) 
{

  managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, "MySharedMemory", 65536);
  const ShmemAllocator alloc_inst (segment.get_segment_manager());
  icons = segment.construct<icons_v>("icons_v")(alloc_inst);
} else {
  managed_shared_memory segment(open_only, "MySharedMemory");
  icons = segment.find<icons_v>("MyVector").first;
}
```

Now, to access vector i can't use standart [] parenthesis because compiler says that using . or -> is error. How do i access vector items?

Answer (score 1):

You generally shouldn't be mixing containers and shared memory. It can be very dangerous if processes built with two different implementations of the container try to work with each other.

You should usually opt for only using native types.

Comment: So you think i should implement native windows API for shared memory?

Comment: No, not if you can make sure that you have the same library version in both processes.

Comment: This is one dll, i should give access to each process attach, but now i can't imagine how to access elements by their index.